# Use convolution and conditional probability method to find $f_Z(z)$

Tags: probability, convolution, conditional-probability

> **Exercise $\boldsymbol{10.44}$.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent continuous random variables with probability density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. Compute $P(X+Y \leq z)$ by first conditioning on $Y=y$ and then using the averaging principle of equation ($10.15$).

This is my work↓

Hint given: $\displaystyle P(X<x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X<x|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy.$

\begin{align}
P(X+Y<z) &= P(X<z-y,Y=y) \\ &=  P(X<z-y) P(Y=y) \tag{by indep.} \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X<z-y|Y=y) f_Y(y) P(Y=y) dy \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{P(X<z-y,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} f_Y(y) P(Y=y) dy \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X<z-y, Y=y) f_Y(y) dy \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \\ \\ \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^z f_{X+Y}(s) ds.
\end{align}

I'm required to use the hint but have no idea how this goes down to the solution.

About Averaging identities:
[image]

Comment: It might help to include the referenced "averaging principle" in the problem.

Comment: I added the definition of the "averaging principle".

Answer (score 1):

If $Z=X+Y$, then
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= P(X+Y)\le z) \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(X\le z-Y|Y=y) f_Y(y)dy,
\end{align}
So that
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= F_Z'(z) \\
&= \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_X(z-y|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy.
\end{align}

Comment: How come d/dz (Fx(z-y|Y=y))=fx(z-y)?

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent and the average is over the distribution of $Y$, the condition is no needed.